# Regex Number To support "," or "/"

Tags: android, ios, regex

I'm tring to find fax number from below regex but it does not work with Fax: (91-44) 7781 1234 or FAX: +91 44 7781 1234,2828 1111

`(?i)fax\\s*\\:\\s*\\+?[/\\(\\d\\)\\s-]+\\d`

This does not support `FAX: +91 44 7781 1234,2828 1111` as it has `,`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a comma to your character range `[\/\(\d\)\s-,]`.

Your regex could look like:

`(?i)fax\\s*\\:\\s*\\+?[/\\(\\d\\)\\s-,]+\\d`

[`(?i)fax\s*\:\s*\+?[\/\(\d\)\s-,]+\d`](https://regex101.com/r/ixDrSk/1/)

Comment: i think this will match `FAX: +91 44 7781 1234, 282` too. But it's wrong fax number `282`

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

`((?:\+\d{2}\s)?(?:\d{2}\s)?\d{4}\s?\d{4})`

tried this on rubular.com and it works fine with your example